# Saiving audio from Media Player

Tags: android, stream, media-player

I'am using Android Media Player to play music from my server. It is possible to save playing audio to storage using MediaPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

`MediaPlayer` class does not support downloading an audio, you will need to download it using http, as far as I remember there `DownloadService` in Android that you can use to download. You can also try to use any library, please [Check this link](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/179)